# how to run a function on chart change in Nuxt Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I want to run a function whenever a chart is loaded/changed in Vue Nuxt JS. I have tried to use created, mounted, updated, beforeMount but all of them are of no use. please help?

Edit 1:
below is the code:

```
    updated(){
        this.adjustFontSize()
        this.removePMFromXAxis()
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.removePMFromXAxis()
    },
    created(){
        this.removePMFromXAxis()
    },
    mounted(){
        this.removePMFromXAxis()

//function
   removePMFromXAxis(){
            // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
            let ticks = document.querySelectorAll(".d3-grouped-area .axis--x .tick");

            ticks.forEach(function(tick) {
                // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
                let textContent = tick.querySelector('text').textContent;
                console.log("textcontent", textContent)
                // eslint-disable-next-line prefer-const
                let updatedTextContent = textContent.replace(/\s[APMapm]{2}\s*$/, '');

                tick.querySelector('text').textContent = updatedTextContent;
            });

        },
```

Comment: which chart library are you using, can you share some code you have tried?

Comment: try with watch or computed property

Comment: i am using d3-vs library @Anis

Comment: Which function is not calling when the chart is loaded/changed? `removePMFromXAxis` or `adjustFontSize` or both?

Comment: removePMfromXAxis

Comment: is there any local data that changes? on which data updates do you wanna trigger the `removePMfromXAxis` function?

Comment: when ever the chart data changes or the chart loads then on that i want to run this function. basically 12PM is appearing in the chart's x axis. i want to remove that everytime the chart loads from new

Comment: when the chart data loads, do you have any data fields that update? how are you storing the new value?

Comment: Any specific field you have added in `data()` option?

Comment: yes there is dataMonthlyCost that feeds into the chart, that is what is updated

Comment: i don't know about the data() thing you are talking about because it is client's code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256678/discussion-between-anis-and-m-waqar-anwar).

Answer (score 0):

To update call the function once data changes we can use [Watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html)

As you mentioned you have `dataMonthlyCost` in [data](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#declaring-reactive-state), we can use watchers such as

```
watch: {
//Whenever dataMonthlyCost changes, this function will run
  dataMonthlyCost(newValue, oldValue) {
    this.removePMFromXAxis()
   }
}
```

Comment: it is not working too sorry for that

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: no, no error, i also tried to console.log but it is not printing, and dataMonthlyCost is a function in computed property

Comment: Try deep watch as https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers

Comment: used deep watch but still of no use

Comment: Are you sure `dataMonthlyCost` updates when chart is loaded/changed?

Comment: yes it changes i have just checked

Comment: i have console.log in deep watch and console.log is working but the function is not working, probably the function runs first and then the chart is updated?

Comment: you can debug the function accordingly, maybe some blockers.